# How to duplicate a Cognito form to be used by another account

Tags: cognito-forms

I have 5 clients currently on Adobe FormsCentral that have forms that are almost but not quite identical. I did extensive modification to one form that I imported to Cognito Forms and I don't want to repeat the work 4 times. How can I duplicate this form?

Answer (score 1):

Great to hear from you!  At present, there is not a way to copy forms from one organization to another.  Never fear, though!  Within the **very** near future, we will have this capability.  Keep an eye on [this card](https://trello.com/c/Rz3vakgn) for updates on the release of this feature.

Update:
Now that this feature is live, I'd like to run through a quick example for future reference.

Here I have created two organizations, "Demonstration" and "Demonstration 2".  I am currently in the "Demonstration 2" organization and am selecting "Copy an existing form" from the New Form dropdown on the home page:

[image: Copy a form]

Selecting the "Demonstration" organization from the menu on the left of the Copy page displays my forms from that organization, at which point I am free to copy the form into my current organization ("Demonstration 2"):

[image: Select source organization]

Hope this helps!

Disclaimer: I'm an engineer on the Cognito Forms team

Comment: Thanks Bobby.  From the description of the enhancement, it sounds like the capability will be form sharing.  That almost meets my need .. except there is one dropdown field that will have different choices for each of the 5 clients.  Will there be a way to handle this?  (The form is an Apartment Rental application; if you would like to make this one of your templates, that would work great. ☺)

Comment: In this case, Allen, we are actually creating a duplicate of the form that is chosen and copying the definition into the destination organization.  On a side-note, if you have a form already built, drop us a line via the site (Write Us) and let us know the org/form name and we'll take a look at it as a possible template!

Comment: Is there an expected release data for the form-sharing enhancement Bobby?

Comment: @AllanThompson, form copying (between orgs that you are a member of) was released a few days ago.. form sharing (between any org) will be available very soon..

Answer (score -1):

TO copy the cognito form from different account please enable the share template option and import that template into your current account